# Is this valid argument in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have ajax code. Here is part of it.

Is it valid to do something like this:

```
$('#addCommentForm'+refID '#files')
```

?

```
$(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {

        var refID = $("#refID").val();
        var file_data = $('#addCommentForm'+refID '#files').prop('files')[0];
```

Comment: Yes it is. You are appending a variable to the Id based selector `#...`. But this `$("#refID").val();` *should* return valid characters to match the actual element ID

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to target multiple elements you can do so by separating them with commas (note the additional +):

```
$('#addCommentForm'+refID+',#files').each(function(){
    $(this).prop('files')[0];
});
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ht03zyzj/1/).